# UE4 - custom template can only start with blueprints

Tags: unreal-4

I tried making a custom template for UE4 to help save some time during gamejams.

I follow this tutorial:

https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Engine/Basics/Projects/CreatingTemplates/index.html

It works alright, even though some minor things don't work, like saving custom folder colors. But what really bothers me is this:
[image: BP only?]

Normally, the options are Blueprint and CPP. I tried making a new template with a different config file, but nothing changes. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: When you've made your template, is it BP only or both BP and C++?

Comment: It was made for BP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a template that's BP only, it will only be available for BP.  To create a C++ template, you need to start with a BP/C++ starter set.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that later and see if that works.